# splitting text with logic inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to use `formula1` and `formula2` to create two new columns in my dataframe, when its says `X` inside the formula used the `x1` column from my `df` to create `formula1` and `formula2`.

```
formula1 = '3.49*X + 3.97'
formula2 = '0.02*X**3 - 0.34*X**2 + 3.41*X + 7.6541'

df

id  x1
 1   4
 2   2
 3   7
```

Expected output

```
df

id  x1  formula1  formula2
 1   4     17.93   17.1341
 2   2     10.95   13.2741
 3   7     28.40   21.7241
```

Comment: I can't understand when you want to use each formula.

Comment: Why not just use `3.49 * df.x1 + 3.97`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use [pandas apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to get new series, assign it to new column, and eval to evaluate string as Python expression.

```
import pandas as pd

inputs = [[1,4], [2,2], [3,7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(inputs, columns=['id', 'x1'])

def get_formula1(x):
    return (eval("3.49 * x + 3.97".replace('x', str(x) )))

def get_formula2(x):
    return (eval("0.02*x**3 - 0.34*x**2 + 3.41*x + 7.6541".replace('x', str(x) )))

df['formula1'] = df['x1'].apply(get_formula1)
df['formula2'] = df['x1'].apply(get_formula2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` could change the string into expression, and `lambda X:` should be added to make it into a function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'x1':[4,2,7]})
formula1 = '3.49*X + 3.97'
formula2 = '0.02*X**3 - 0.34*X**2 + 3.41*X + 7.6541'
formulas = {'formula1':formula1,
            'formula2':formula2}
for formula in formulas:
    df[formula] = df['x1'].apply(eval('lambda X:'+formulas[formula]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin it should be something like this:

```
df['formula1'] = 3.49*df['x1'] + 3.97
df['formula2'] = 0.02*df['x1']**3 - 0.34*df['x1']**2 + 3.41*df['x1'] + 7.6541
```